# How to implement a countdown timer for camera in ios?

Tags: ios

Hi I am trying to to create a countdown timer in camera. I have tried using the NSTimer but i was not able to show up the timer in camera. I am following objective c

Comment: please view this link for custom camera with timer option https://github.com/liman123/custom-camera

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I am new to ios so the code is a bit difficult for me. If you can then please help me with something which can be easily understood for a beginner

Comment: have you run that code ???

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something similar to this:

```
@IBOutlet var countDownLabel: UILabel!

var counter = 10

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func update() {
    if(count > 0) {
        countDownLabel.text = String(counter--)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help but iam looking for objective c code

Comment: You didn't specify that in you question previously...

Comment: sorry my mistake